# The notification display content from the previous notification when app goes in background

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, inappbrowser

I have implemented an in-app browser within the activity `ViewInWeb`. I use this `activity` to  open the news inside the application. I also use this activity to open push notifications that contain links. But the following problem occurs:

1. I open a link from the application in `ViewInWeb`
2. I press home button so the application goes in background
3. I get a notification that contains a link.
4. When I open the notification, it does not display the content from this notification, but it display the content that was before I pressed Home Button.

When I open a notification, I use the following code:

```
                Intent resultIntent;
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = null;

                resultIntent =new Intent(this, ViewInWeb.class);
                Bundle basket = new Bundle();
                basket.putString(TimeUtils.TAG_LINK,link );
                basket.putString(TimeUtils.TAG_TITLE,title );
                basket.putInt("TYPE", 1);
                resultIntent.putExtras(basket);

                resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, Integer.parseInt(nr),
                        resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

The code for `ViewInWeb` is like below:

```
public class ViewInWeb extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    private String link, title;
    private String url_link, url_title;
    private int count = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_in_web);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser_web_view);

        // enable back button
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close_black);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
               .
               .
            //code for Google Analytics tracking
               .
                }
                count++;
            }
        });

        //get the data
        Bundle basket_category = getIntent().getExtras();
        link = basket_category.getString(TimeUtils.TAG_LINK);
        title = basket_category.getString(TimeUtils.TAG_TITLE);
        int type = basket_category.getInt("TYPE");
        if(type==1){

               .
               .
            //code for Google Analytics tracking
               .
        }
        url_link = link;
        url_title = title;

        //put the data
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        webView.loadUrl(link);

        // create new ProgressBar and style it
        final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);

        progressBar.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 25));

        // retrieve the top view of our application
        final FrameLayout decorView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.addView(progressBar);

        ViewTreeObserver observer = progressBar.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                View contentView = decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                //progressBar.offsetTopAndBottom(contentView.getBottom()-10);
                float x = contentView.getBottom();

                int result = 0;
                int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
                if (resourceId > 0) {
                    result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
                }

                Log.e("aggbfaevfsa", String.valueOf(x));
                progressBar.setY(contentView.getY() + result - 10);
                // progressBar.setX(0);

                ViewTreeObserver observer = progressBar.getViewTreeObserver();
                observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });


        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            // page loading progress, gone when fully loaded
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (progress < 100 && progressBar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                }
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                if (progress == 100) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
                super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
                    url_link = view.getUrl();
                    url_title = title;
                }
            }
        });
        // set the animation when opening the activity
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_open_translate,
                R.anim.activity_close_scale);

    }

    // set the animation when closing the activity
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // closing transition animations
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_open_scale,
                R.anim.activity_close_translate);
    }


}
```

The same problem occur when two notifications come in the app. After I have opened the first one, I press the home button. When I press the second, it displays the content of the first one.

Any idea how to solve the issue.

Comment: did you use getIntent method and get the link form the intent and try to use onPause and onResume methods- post full source code of ViewinWeb

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `onCreate()` might not be called, once application in the background (it's activity might not be destroyed yet).

So here's what you can do in your `ViewInWeb` activity instead of handling new intent in `onCreate()`:

```
public class ViewInWeb extends AppCompatActivity {
    ......
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         ....
         //initialize your widgets, as you did, but don't start loading data
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        handleIntent();
    }

    private void handleIntent() {
        // handle intent here!

        Bundle basket_category = getIntent().getExtras();
        link = basket_category.getString(TimeUtils.TAG_LINK);
        title = basket_category.getString(TimeUtils.TAG_TITLE);
        int type = basket_category.getInt("TYPE");
        if(type==1){
            //code for Google Analytics tracking
        }
        url_link = link;
        url_title = title;
        //put the data
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        webView.loadUrl(link);
    }
}
```

NB! If you use fragments, it recommends to handle intent from `protected void onResumeFragments()` method instead of simple `onResume()`

I hope, it helps